# no space left on device on docker desktop for macos and skaffold

Tags: docker, skaffold

I had tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668660/docker-no-space-left-on-device-macos), specifically:

1. run `docker system prune`, which freed about 6GB
2. increased the `Disk image size` on docker desktop preferences to `64 GB (43 GB used)`

but am still seeing this when running skaffold: `exiting dev mode because first build failed: couldn't build "user/orders": docker build: Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /tsconfig.json: no space left on device`.  Another run of skaffold gave me this on another occasion:

```
exiting dev mode because first build failed: couldn't build "exiting dev mode because first build failed: couldn't build "user/orders": unable to stream build output: failed to create rwlayer: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/7c6618702ad15fe0fa7d4655109aa6326fb4f954df00d2621f62d66d7b328ed9/diff: no space left on device
```

Also, when running `docker system df`, I see this:

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          10        0         28.86GB   28.86GB (100%)
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   30        0         15.62GB   15.62GB (100%)
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

I also have about 200GB of physical hard drive space available.

I'm hoping I don't have to manually run `rm *` as [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device), which was for a linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

if you're running on Mac and have 200GB free, will increasing help you?

[image]

Comment: @reactor did you try that?

Comment: I did, but that didn't help. I decided to use minikube instead