# docker needs huge disk space on macOS

Tags: macos, docker, diskspace

Following up on
[docker no space left on device macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668660/docker-no-space-left-on-device-macos)

I found that docker needs huge space on macOS

[image]

This is for creating the following docker images (with packer):

```
CREATED        SIZE  
   6 hours ago    81.7GB
   8 hours ago    80.5GB
   14 hours ago   230MB 
   14 hours ago   153MB
```

I.e., it is taking nearly 1/3 of my total disk spaces, and I need to allocate nearly half of my total disk spaces. Why it is taking so much space?

I've been building the same images under Linux and Windows and never had I been running out of allocated space and need to allocate more disk space again and again before.

```
% docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          4         0         162.5GB   162.5GB (100%)
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   2         0         350.5MB   350.5MB (100%)
Build Cache     5         0         0B        0B

% df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   932Gi   10Gi  555Gi     2%  488001 9767490159    0%   /
devfs          194Ki  194Ki    0Bi   100%     673          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s2   932Gi  363Gi  555Gi    40%  712613 9767265547    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s5   932Gi  2.0Gi  555Gi     1%       2 9767978158    0%   /private/var/vm
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
map -fstab       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/Network/Servers
/dev/disk1s4   932Gi  507Mi  555Gi     1%      54 9767978106    0%   /Volumes/Recovery
/dev/disk2s1   1.8Gi  1.5Gi  323Mi    83%   17770 4294949509    0%   /Volumes/Docker
```

The above reports look reasonable to me, where have the remaining ~150G space gone to?